# Is there anything built into the WordPress core to enable me to get the relative path from the "permalink structure" option

Tags: permalinks

I fear I am going to have to write a bunch of code to get what I need, which is fine, but I want to check to see if there's anything in-built before I embark on that journey.

I am working on a plugin and I need to get the relative path for a given `permalink_structure`. Currently, the permalink structure option returns `/%postname%/%post_id%/`. I have the post (page) id e.g. 100.

From what the permalink is set up as, I know the full relative path should be `/iamapost/100`. However, it seems the best I can do is the following:

```
get_permalink($post_id) === "https://example.com/iamapost/";
parse_url(get_permalink($post_id), PHP_URL_PATH) === "/iamapost/";
get_post_permalink($post_id) === "https://example.com/?post_type=page&p=100";
get_site_uri  === "https://example.com";
```

Given that:

```
get_option('permalink_structure') === "/%postname%/%post_id%/";
```

Can the relative path be taken from this or any permalink structure set up on the permalink settings page - whatever that might be...

[image: permalink settings page]

***Please, please do not assume this is a duplicate, because I really have searched and no question and answer is specific to reacting to whatever the permalink structure is at the time. If such an answer exists, then cool.***

Comment: ***What's the reason for needing the relative URL?*** I notice you say that the full relative path should be `/iamapost/100` but this is clearly not true because you stated that `get_permalink` returns `https://example.com/iamapost/` not `https://example.com/iamapost/100` therefore this `/100` part is not in the permalink and you have a separate independent problem. The literal answer to your question is actually the second line of your code block with `parse_url`

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell the reason is that the plugin creates a URL via a server side batch process for distribution outside of WordPress based on which page a relevant shortcode is in. In this case using `has_shortcode` and `get_shortcode_regex` to find the page. In this example the page_id is 100. The total URL should reflect whatever the user has set the `permalink_structure` to.

Comment: I didn't quite follow that, you want to share the URLs of these posts but want them to be relative URLs for unknown reasons. The missing `100` has nothing to do with your question/relative URLs, and is a new and different unrelated problem. You already know the  answer to this question, it's `parse_url(get_permalink($post_id), PHP_URL_PATH)`. The reason you could not find a solution to this problem is because you were researching the wrong problem and already knew the solution to what you were searching for. `parse_url` can't insert the `/100` if it was never in the permalink to begin with

Comment: I need the `permalink_structure` relative path eg `/imapost/100/` because the full path may include other options e.g. a shebang to support the plethera of JavaScript frameworks which navigate by  lazyloading pages via the REST api. The plugin already checks for a shebang. Also, there maybe query string added to links. A querystring will come before or after the relative path depending on whether a shebang is used. Note, the `permalink_structure` could be anything.

Comment: The `#foo` part of a URL never gets sent to the server, it's 100% client side. But if it did get sent, the solution is still the same. Likewise if you read the docs for `parse_url`, query strings are also handled. Your problem is not related to parsing the URL, it is that the result of `get_permalink` does not contain `/100` therefore the permalink does not contain `/100`.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question on how to solve your permalink problem? This isn't a discussion forum/thread, you asked if WP has an API or helper for getting relative URLs, not how to include `/100` in your permalinks.

Comment: I updated my answer after trying to reproduce your problem with a local WordPress installation, and managed to produce the results you wanted using the code you provided. I edited my answer to include screenshots and direct code output. Whatever the cause of your problem is, this is not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything built into the WordPress core to enable me to get the relative path from the “permalink structure” option

No, because it isn't necessary, PHP provides this via `parse_url`. Using `php -a` we can launch an interactive PHP shell and test the code:

```
php > echo parse_url( 'http://example.com/iamapost/100', PHP_URL_PATH );
/iamapost/100
php >
```

If we read the PHP docs we see that it also handles query strings, etc, e.g.:

```php
php > echo parse_url( 'http://example.com/iamapost/100?foo=bar#test', PHP_URL_PATH );
/iamapost/100
php >
```

**Your problem is not retrieving the relative URL.**

Your results do not contain the `/100` because your permalinks do not contain it. Run `echo get_permalink();` and it will become obvious. You are assuming that your permalinks contain the post ID. *They do not.*

> Given that:
>
> ```
> get_option('permalink_structure') === "/%postname%/%post_id%/";
> ```
>
> Can the relative path be taken from this or any permalink structure set up on the permalink settings page - whatever that might be...

**Yes**, via `get_permalink()` and `parse_url`.

I decided to spin up a local site of WP v5.6.1, and gave it the permalink structure you used:

[image]

I then fired up `wp shell` and ran the code and got the expected results:

```
vagrant@vvv:/srv/www/wordpress-one/public_html$ wp shell
wp> echo parse_url(get_permalink(168), PHP_URL_PATH);
/test-2/168/
wp> echo get_option('permalink_structure');
/%postname%/%post_id%/
wp>
```

Comment: Thx bud. I'll see if I can debug to see where it's going wrong. If I find out that it's a different problem, and I need help, I guess I should ask a different question right? As such, I'll accept this answer as correct. If I find out why I'm getting the wrong path, I'll let you know. 

Comment: I tried to think of a situation that might end up with your problem, it could be that the `permalink_structure` option was changed directly but rewrite rules/permalinks were not flushed/resaved. It could be the the post permalink URL function is being filtered, or that rewrite rules are being changed via hooks. That last one can be confirmed via a plugin such as monkeyman rewrite rules analyser, the first one can be tested by flushing permalinks, and the second _might_ be testable by  changing the permalink structure and seeing if `get_permalink` gives the same value

Comment: Thx for the leads! 

Comment: It seems it's to do with the post being a page. Inside `get_permalink`: `get_page_link` > `_get_page_link` > `get_page_permastruct` is the callstack. This does not look at the permalink_structure, but instead just uses `%postname%`.

Comment: Pages do not work the same way as posts, if they didn't then parent/child paths would not work

Comment: All sorted now. The theme was using the pageid to use lazy load each page. It's now using `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=pagename`